# C++ Unzip and parse csv using zip.h

Tags: c++, csv, unzip

I have a file myfile.zip that contains a csv that I am trying to parse. I have created a structure like the following:

```
struct Customer {
    int id;
    double quantity;
    long timestamp;
};
```

i have linked

```
#include <zip.h>
```

But I do not manage to unzip and directly read the csv to get the data in a vector.

I did this:

```
vector<Customer> read_data(const string& filename) {
    vector<Customer> customers;
    ifstream file(filename);
    string line;
    getline(file, line);
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        Customer customer;
        stringstream ss(line);
        ss >> customer.id >> customer.quantity >> customer.quantity >> customer.timestamp;
        customers.push_back(customer);
    }
    file.close();
    return customers;
}
```

But it does not manage to unzip I believe and so it gives 000
Any idea how I could please?

Comment: where is your code? including a header and defining a data structure is not going to read a csv file. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Solve each problem independently. For the csv problem there are many questions here that already solve this problem.

Comment: Your csv code looks fine but it looks like you did not unzip the file first.

Comment: _"it does not manage to unzip"_ - you haven't posted  any code for unzipping.

Comment: Cause I don't manage to unzip

Comment: @NicolasREY Have you read the documentation of the zip library? I suggest you write the code that unzips the file. And then you parse the unzipped csv file. That's two independent problems. Apparently your actual questions is _"How can I use the zip library to unzip a file"_ which is a question that is not focused enough.

Comment: Your question was closed because you did not show an attempt to solve the problem you wanted. Also asking about 2 independent tasks unzip and csv would not be a single focused problem. If you need help with the unzip part forget about csv and show an attempt to solve that problem.

Comment: yes I tried but i dont understand. I'm new in c++

Comment: But I dont want to unzip and save on disk. I would like to unzip and directly parse the data to keep the zip, so the two thimgs are linked

Comment: It's much easier to extract to a file and process the file. You can just extract to a temporary folder if needed. I don't believe extracting directly is a "I'm new in c++" task although I think you can do that with Boost: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330645/read-and-write-array-to-compressed-file-with-boost-iostreams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330645/read-and-write-array-to-compressed-file-with-boost-iostreams)

Comment: " so the two thimgs are linked" sure in your final program you want to do both. But if you dont know how to unzip something, and before you know how to parse a plain csv file, you will also not manage to parse a csv file that comes from a zip. Though if you know how to do the two steps separately, then combining them is merely doing one after the other, because a zip library does not care what the data actually is and code that parses a csv should not depend on where the csv comes from

Comment: for csv, I guess its one of the most elaborate give-away-code-almost-ready-to-be-used q&a there is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c

Comment: for the unzipping you must read the manual of the library you are using.

Comment: I don;t understand anything to http://www.zlib.net/